# cv2 destroyWindow() does not work in ros callback function

Tags: python, opencv, ros

I am getting data from a 3d simulation, specifically the lidar and camera of a robot. I want to show the camera images with cv2 whenever the robot detects an object closer than a set threshold around it. However the images are displayed fine when an object is within the specified distance but when the robot stops detecting an object within the threshold the window is not destroyed and it is stuck displaying the last shown image. If i get in range of an object again the window still does not update with the new images.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
import cv2
from cv_bridge import CvBridge, CvBridgeError
from sensor_msgs.msg import LaserScan
from sensor_msgs.msg import Image

bridge = CvBridge()
threshold = 0.5
sub_camera = None
window_name = "Camera preview"

def scan_callback(scan):
    global sub_camera
    if(min(scan.ranges) < threshold):
        rospy.loginfo("Object detected")
        if(not sub_camera):
            sub_camera = rospy.Subscriber("/camera/rgb/image_raw", Image, image_callback)
    else:
        rospy.loginfo("No object detected")
        if(sub_camera):
            cv2.destroyWindow(window_name)
            sub_camera.unregister()
            sub_camera = None

def image_callback(img):
    try:
        cv_image = bridge.imgmsg_to_cv2(img, "bgr8") 
    except CvBridgeError as e:
        rospy.logerr("CvBridge Error: {0}".format(e))

    cv2.namedWindow(window_name)
    cv2.imshow(window_name, cv_image)
    cv2.waitKey(1)

rospy.init_node('camera_lidar_node', anonymous=False)
sub_lidar = rospy.Subscriber("/scan", LaserScan, scan_callback)

while not rospy.is_shutdown():
    rospy.spin()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`waitKey()` does GUI event processing.

You have to be in that call continuously or frequently. If you are not, the GUI freezes.

You should use the GUI facilities of ROS itself. Those are made for ROS.